# Correct way to find the source of GC overhead limit exceeded exceptions

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a legacy code which is very complex.
Executing it, from time to time, generates `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : GC overhead limit exceeded`

What will be the right approach to identify the source of this?
Code is very complex (multiple hashmaps, strings manipulations and etc)

Comment: I have a visualVM, there is a visual GC tab that shows GC hits, but it doesn't show me the code that causes those hits.

Comment: Take a heap dump and check for *number of instances* of classes. Check [this link](https://visualvm.java.net/heapdump.html)

Comment: GC isn't "caused" by any specific code. Can you increase the heap size?

Comment: @laune, already did and it helped but i want to identify the root of this.

Comment: @TheLostMind, there are a lot of classes, some had a lot of instances it still won't guarantee that they  are the cause  of this problem.

Comment: @Tirmean - If you say a *heap* dump won't help you, then I wonder what will :(

Comment: This simply happens if the GC is forced to run too often as available heap space is almost exhausted - not once, but repeatedly, and GC can't ever recover enough. If the application runs fine with more memory, then that's what it takes, and you'll have to increase heap size.

Comment: @TheLostMind, for example I see 5k instances of Strings  which are 17%
on the second place char[] which are 16%

Comment: @Tirmean - You will have to check why the strings are not GCed. Which classes / instances hold references to them etc.

Comment: TheLostMind, code works with text files, there are a lot of places that work with Strings, it will be extremely difficult all those places.

Comment: 5k instances of String is next to nothing. With an average length of, say, 40, you are looking at approx. 5000.120 bytes, which is 600k.

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : GC overhead limit exceeded` is caused by the GC spending a too high amount of CPU time relative to the amount of CPU time spent in application code.

In other words, the GC estimates that it is making insufficient progress to keep the application going at reasonable throughput.

There are 3 possible causes for this:

- A) some code creating truly massive amounts of objects while spending otherwise fairly little CPU time (thus GC time exceeding the overhead limit)
- B) your heap was simply too small and your application just happened to trigger *overhead limit reached* instead of *insufficient memory*
- C) you have a slow memory leak and the GC is running out of breathing room and just happens to throw *overhead limit reached* before it gets into the *insufficient memory* situation

To pinpoint A) you'll need a profile allocation rates.

B) can be solved simply by bumping up the heap limit.

C) is different from B) in that it still throws after bumping up the heap size. In that case you simply should enable `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` and analyze the dump for leaked objects.

In a few cases it's possible that the heuristic is misguided. In those cases one can either relax the limit by adjusting `-XX:GCTimeRatio=` to allow the GC to burn more CPU time or simply disable it entirely with `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit`. But in most cases that would just delay the inevitable *insufficient memory* OOM.

Answer (score -1):

If Java didn't impose a limit on how much time it could spend in garbage-collection, a program which would require a quantity of memory that's just below the amount that's available might never "fail", but might take *thousands of times longer* to execute than it would have with somewhat more memory.  Conversely, a program which requires a total amount of memory might end up failing with insufficient memory, but might spend an extremely long time getting almost nothing done before that happened.  The implementers of Java added some GC-time sanity checks on the philosophy that having a program which would normally take one second to execute fail with an out-of-memory error after a couple seconds is better than having the program chug away for an hour and then throw an out-of-memory error, and isn't really much worse than having it chug away for an hour and possibly succeed.

Unless a program is deliberately forcing garbage-collections, cost per kilobyte of temporary allocations will will be vaguely proportional to the number of live objects divided by the amount of free space that would be left after a collection.  This amount will go from being quite small to really huge as memory utilization approaches a certain level.  Consequently, having memory allocations fail at the point when they would otherwise get really slow will effectively reduce the amount of memory available to a program, but not by much.